# About Ordering Regression

Tags: math, statistics

I read a paper about ordering logistic regression. And I don't understand why we can get the formula "b_q - f(x)" [(please refer this picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqxv4.png)

If you have any advice or reference and share for me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Interesting question, however, it's off topic in this forum; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. Also, it will help others help you if you show your own work on it. I think a more common name for it is "ordinal logistic regression"; try a web search for that term.

Answer (score 0):

b_q is the (left) threshold defined for class q. f(x) represents a one-dimensional mapping of the data. g is the link function. Together, we get that P(y<C_q|x)=g(b_q-f(x)).